# How to use Super key as modifer without Unity and Compiz?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, shortcuts

How can I use the Super key as modifier in 11.04? I don't have Unity and Compiz, I am using classic mode.

When I press the Super key and, for example, `S`, (I want a shortcut like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) in "Keyboard shortcuts" in settings, I get "Multi_key", as Super key no longer a modifier.

Before 11.04 <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> denote <kbd>Mod4</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in "Keyboard shortcuts".

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm trying to make Mod4+L be the shortcut for locking the screen. Upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04 w/ Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and changed the compose key. It works!

Answer (score 0):

If you use neighter unity nor gnome what are you using?

The „Keyboard Shortcuts“ works only when a gnome-app is running (e.g. gnome-panel). I doesn't work for example for fvwm or wm ;-).

Comment: I use gnome classic without gnome-panel (i use awn). But before 11.04 it works perfectly. And now „Keyboard Shortcuts“ working, but i can't set super key as a modificator.